# "Rubric" as meaning "signature" or "personal mark" -- is this accepted usage?

Tags: word-usage

I am reading a book about Spanish California, and the author uses the word "rubric" to mean, I think, "personal mark attesting to a document." I don't have access to the original manuscript documents, so I can't tell if this refers to a signature, an "X," or some other sort of mark. Any thoughts on this usage?

Example from the end of a report (translated by the author from Spanish to English):

> This is what we have seen.
>   Frontier of Santo Domingo, January 15, 1780.
>   Joseph Velásquez (Rubric)

Answer (score 15):

The Oxford English Dictionary has this definition:

> In Spanish- and Portuguese-speaking contexts: a decorative flourish attached to a signature; (also) a mark used in place of a signature. Now chiefly *hist*.

Notably, it was used in [Don Quixote](https://books.google.com/books?id=acjK7K6l4AAC&pg=PA57-IA1&lpg=PA57-IA1&dq=%E2%80%9Csubscribed;%20not%20only%20for%20three%20Asses,%20but%20also%20for%20three%20hundred.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=yMJqhyjzjV&sig=ACfU3U026U11iNi0stdbD2V_2-CtntcevQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj10o3prOnhAhVjzlkKHSZTDOYQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Csubscribed%3B%20not%20only%20for%20three%20Asses%2C%20but%20also%20for%20three%20hundred.%E2%80%9D&f=false):

> It goes very well (quoth Sancho) subsigne it therefore I pray you. It needes no seale (quoth Don-Quixote) but onely my Rubricke [Sp. *rúbrica*], which is as valible as if it were subscribed; not only for three Asses, but also for three hundred.

However this sense of the word is not in Oxford’s [general dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rubric). It’s not a definition that the vast majority of people know.

Comment: Just to add the modern usage in Portuguese (I'm a native speaker): in modern days, rubric means a "short" version of the signature, normally just the first letter of the person's name. When reviewing a long contract, for instance, the lawyer would say to you *"please rubric every page and sign the last one"* (using "rubric" as a verb here).

Comment: I couldn't even remember the academic definition. OP  is trying to use an obscure definition of an already obscure word.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this source](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/39633/when-were-signature-rubrics-called-for), a rubric is the flourish or swash under a signature:

> A rubric is a flourish embellishing a signature; it's both decorative and a security feature.

[history.stackexchange.com]

I'm not sure how credible that website is as a source, but this meaning seems to be confirmed by other references, for example:

> The flourish or rubric in the occidental signatures is defined by a kind of doodle written much faster and without much attention.

[*Modeling the Lexical Morphology of Western Handwritten Signatures*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4393123/),
PLOS One

Or:

> A flourish after a signature; a paraph.

From [wordnik.com](https://www.wordnik.com/words/rubric) quoting the Century Dictionary